# J language async programming (event driven)

Tags: j

J code seems to me like a big "math function" that maps input to output (very functional).

I wonder if J (maybe inside jqt) also supports the code pattern of asynchronous/callback function kind of

```
    async_run(read_from_serial_port, call_back_fun(data){
           display(after_processing(data))
           })

    keep_on_doing_something_else
```

The idea is to make a gui (real-time, non-blocking) that plots data reading back from the serial port in J.

Comment: There are ways to achieve this, but nothing off-the-shelf.  The sockets library on Windows does provide async mode with callbacks, but that's about the only library that does.  For anything else, you'll have to use `wd'timer'` (i.e polling, as is done for sockets on Linux), or the `cdcallback` mechanisms and roll your own DLL/SO bridge. Note that `wd` is implemented in the the J session manager, and is a no-op in jconsole (for example).

Comment: +1 to wanting something like this. I'm even more greedy and would want something like FRP or Promises/A+ for higher-level control of "things that may happen later".  Wish I could help with this but I'm still a newbie.